# How to pass arguments to android application on startup?

Tags: python, android, android-studio, samsung-mobile, monkeyrunner

I am building a simple test application that places a button somewhere on the screen. I want to be able to control this placement x,y on startup. If I start the activity using monkeyrunner, for example, what is the best way to tell the application where I want to place the button?

Comment: welcome to Android! probably putting two `EditText` elements and one `Button` in the layout so that you can enter the x and y values and then hit the button!

Comment: @Soheil I believe the OP wants to place the button on "startup." Ann - You can set the position of the button in the **XML** file.